# Using NSNumberFormatter to pad spaces between a currency symbol and the value

Tags: iphone, cocoa, currency, padding, nsnumberformatter

Apologies if this is a dumb question but I'm trying to format a currency value for my iphone app and am struggling to left-justify the currency symbol, but right-justify the value. So, "$123.45" is formatted as (say)

```
$   123.45
```

depending on format-width. This is a kind of accounting format (I think).

I've tried various methods with NSNumberFormatter but can't get what I need.

Can anyone advise on how to do this?

Thanks

Fitto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `paddingPosition` property of `NSNumberFormatter`. You need to set this to `NSNumberFormatterPadAfterPrefix` for the desired format.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked a treat. Thanks

Comment: It's important to note that this only works when formatWidth is set, as per the question.

Answer (score 4):

This didn't work for me. I was able to add a space between the currency symbol and the amount by doing this.

**Swift 3.0**

```
currencyFormatter.negativePrefix = "\(currencyFormatter.negativePrefix!) "
currencyFormatter.positivePrefix = "\(currencyFormatter.positivePrefix!) "
```

Complete code:

```
extension Int {
    func amountStringInCurrency(currencyCode: String) -> (str: String, nr: Double) {
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
        currencyFormatter.negativePrefix = "\(currencyFormatter.negativePrefix!) "
        currencyFormatter.positivePrefix = "\(currencyFormatter.positivePrefix!) "

        let nrOfDigits = currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits
        let number: Double = Double(self)/pow(10, Double(nrOfDigits))
        return (currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))!, number)
    }
}
```

This extension is on an Int that expresses the amount in MinorUnits. I.e. USD is expressed with 2 digits, while japanese yen is expressed without digits. So this is what this extension would return:

```
let amountInMinorUnits: Int = 1234
amountInMinorUnits.amountStringInCurrency(currencyCode: "USD").str // $ 12.34
amountInMinorUnits.amountStringInCurrency(currencyCode: "JPY").str // JP¥ 1,234
```

The thousand and decimal separator are determined by the users locale.